# After successfully installed apk file in my google nexus 7 tablet 4.1 but i cant open that app, it will close unfortunately

Tags: android

1. I have installed my apk file in htc android mobile successfully.
2. I can able to open and access that app successfully.
3. At the same apk file again i install in google nexus 7 tablet 4.1
   jellybean version successfully.
4. After installation, when i click to open,error for "**unfortunately
   app has Stopped**"..

   (Note : i have configured also for tablet land large portrait view also..)

I don't know what to do. Please anyone help me

Comment: maybe in the manifest the tagetVersion is specified lower than 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device to the computer with USB cable and type `adb logcat` soon after you have your application misbehave, resulting logcat output should give you clues about what's wrong and how to fix it. If you are unable to figure out the fix, post the logcat in your question, otherwise nobody would be able to help you, there are too many ways the application can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to connect your HTC to the computer to see the LogCat, just go to **Play Store** and search for the app **aLogCat**, and after that try to re-open your app and when you see this error again, go to aLogCat and you will see exactly what is going wrong.